# Cant modify ArrayList elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a database of articles written by more than one authors, so I have two classes: Author and Article. 
The constructor for Article is

```
        Article(String title, String venue, Author[] authors, long year).
```

An Author object contains a String with the name of the author and an ArrayList of articles he has written.

So, I have an array of Articles, and I'm trying to create an ArrayList of Authors and add all the articles they have written.

This is my code:

```
for(int i=0; i<allarticles.length; i++) {
            Author[] tempauthors = allarticles[i].getAuthors();
            for (int j=0; j<tempauthors.length; j++) {
                Author tempauthor = tempauthors[j];
                if (authors.contains(tempauthor)) {
                    Author oldAuthor = authors.get(authors.indexOf(tempauthor));
                    if (!oldAuthor.hasArticle(allarticles[i]))
                        oldAuthor.addArticle(allarticles[i]);
                } else {
                    if (!tempauthor.hasArticle(allarticles[i]))
                        tempauthor.addArticle(allarticles[i]);
                    authors.add(tempauthor);
                }
            }
        }
```

and here's the hasArticle method:
    public boolean hasArticle(Article a) {
        return articles.contains(a);
    }

I modified the equals method as suggested but now the problem is that I get authors with the right amount of articles but the first one is duplicated. What I am doing wrong? Should I ovverride the Article.equals() method as well?

Comment: Reread the chapter on object references, identity and `equals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the Author class has its own mechanism for returning the same Author object for each instance of an Author object where the name is the same, the code is working correctly.

The contains() method doesn't "know" that you're referring to an author by name, it only knows that you've asked if the specific Author object is in the ArrayList.

The contains() method compares the entire object using its equals(Object a) method.  Two different objects are equal, if and only if, the equals() methods says they are.  For a class without an explicit equals() method (other than the one inherited from Object or another class your class extends), the address (pointer ...) is used.

So, you have to define what "equals()" means.  In your case, two objects are equal if the name of the authors are equal.  In your case, that means equals() is this method --

```
public boolean equals(Object a) {
  if (! (a instanceof Author))
    return false;

  return this.getname().equals(((Author) a).getname());
}
```

You also seem to have some funky logic in your code.  You want to add the new article to the existing articles the author has.  So you need to find the existing entry for that author (indexOf() method in ArrayList), get that entry (get() method ...) then add the article to the Author object already in the ArrayList.

To do this, you'll need to do

```
Author oldAuthor = authors.get(authors.indexOf(tempauthor));
oldAuthor.addArticle(allarticles[i]);
```

instead of the remove / addArticle / remove code you have.

You will also need to make sure that you aren't adding an article to the author's list of articles that you've already added.

Comment: Did you make the change to STOP removing the existing author and their articles, but to instead using indexOf(tempauthor) to find the existing entry, then say that the existing entry has the article added to it?  Sorry I didn't give the complete answer, but @SLaks kept steering you down the "fix the equals method" rabbit hole.

Comment: @tonydanza: That's because the author already has the article in their list of articles.  Sorry -- you need to make sure that the article you're adding isn't already in the list, which it will be (as I understand your code now) already.  That is, each author starts off with one article.  When that article is found again in allArticles, the authors of that article then have that article added to their list of articles.

Comment: @tonydanza: You don't have enough reputation to "chat".  Let's do this -- edit your code above and then delete your responses.  I'll do likewise and we go at it some more.  The formatting in comments is horrible, but what you wrote =should= work.  Except that I probably can't see the bug because of the bad formatting ...

Comment: @tonydanza: You probably need to do that as well, but be prepared to find a bug or to in addArticle(), depending on how that is written.  How about posting more code?  That and deleting your responses in this now very long discussion.

Comment: ok Julie, I defined the Article.equals method and now it works. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Author.equals()` to return `true` for different but equivalent `Author` instances.

Comment: I tried with:
    public boolean equals(Author a) {
  return this.getName().equals(a);
 }
but it doesnt work.

Comment: @tonydanza: That's because `getName()` (a `string`) will never equal `a` (an `Author`).  Also, you need to **override** `equals()`, which take `Object`.

Comment: Got it, still doesnt work though. My method is 
`public boolean equals(Object a) {
  Author aut = (Author)a;
  return this.getName().equals(aut.getName());
 }`
but I get all the authors having two duplicate articles, like
Author x: article "Title1", article "Title1".

Comment: @SLaks: The logic is also bad.  Even if the equals() method were fixed, the code would still be broken. In fact, fixing the equals() method breaks the code -- the previous Author object in the list can now be removed because it can be compared equal to.